# SiriKit Intents UI - Payment Domain Remove "Send Money" bar

Tags: ios, ios10, sirikit

I'm trying to create a custom UI for my SiriKit extension in the Payments domain. However, the UI is still showing the "Send Money" bar in the confirmation stage and the "Money Sent" bar in the handling stage. Is it possible to remove these?

Answer (score 2):

No, It is not not possible to remove it. Only the center area is customizable using configure method of IntentsUI.

Comment: Can we add custom UIButton with action in this center area?